# Primefaces calendar : Not able to format the date

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

**Updated** : I have used primefaces calendar to show dates. It's default format is mm/dd/yy but for other locale like german it is dd.mm.yy. If I specify the format for english for example dd/MM/yyyy then it shows correct format for english but then on changing language to german it shows again dd/MM/yyyy instead of dd.MM.yyyy

I have tried this :

```
<p:calendar id="createdDateToDK"
    value="#{messagesDefaultKeys.createdDateTo}" showOn="button"
                mode="popup" navigator="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy>
                <f:converter converterId="messages.convertors.DateConvertor" />
</p:calendar>
```

I have tried below also:

```
<p:calendar id="createdDateToDK"
            value="#{messagesDefaultKeys.createdDateTo}" showOn="button"
            mode="popup" navigator="true">
            <f:convertDateTime for="createdDateToDK" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"></f:convertDateTime>
</p:calendar>
```

I am using primefaces3.5 jar and JSF2.0 .

I do not want to add another calendar component just for another language . Please note that this happens only when I specify the format for calendar else while it works well with different locales.

Comment: there are a error in first example: on 
pattern="MM/dd/yyyy  missing closing quote.
I usualy use first example.

Comment: what type is createdDateTo ? I see you use a convertor

Comment: Ah.... maybe a missing quote :( but now there is another problems same format is for all the locales for example for german it is same as english dd/MM/yyyy instead it should be dd.mm.yyyy createDateTo is of java.util.Date format

Comment: try to send format as an EL expression from an bean field

Comment: using String pattern1 = ((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale)).toPattern(); you get the default date format for specified locale

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a converter for dates, `calendar` comes with an attribute called pattern, you can use it to change the pattern of dates, for exemple `<p:calendar pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" />` this will show `21.02.2017 15:42`, you can change the pattern to separate the date however you like using dots, slach or any character

Comment: Yes but if follow this approach then localization stops working, for every locale pattern will be same.

Comment: You need to include primefaces locales. See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Locales